# How to open new tab with Button click in Safari with extension?

Tags: html, macos, safari, onclick, safari-extension

I am having issues opening a new tab in Safari browser with my extension.
Using the Extension Builder I added `bar.html`:

```
<html>
<body>
  <form id="myForm">
    <input type="button" value="Button1" onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com')"/>
    <button onclick='window.open("https://www.google.com", "_blank");'>Button2</button>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Neither of **Button1** nor **Button2** will open 'google.com' in a new tab, nor window. If I put them in a form as above, and click on **Button2** it will open my `bar.html` in the current tab, and from there if I click either **Button1** or **Button2** it will open 'google.com' in my current tab.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this in Apple Dev library and it states "**The standard window.open() method cannot be used to open a new tab and window from an extension bar. Instead, extension bars have access to the SafariApplication, SafariBrowserWindow, and SafariBrowserTab classes, which allow you to open, close, activate, and manipulate windows and tabs."**

So by using a function with `safari.self.browserWindow.openTab` I was able to open my link in a new tab.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Safari Developer Reference</title>
        <button onclick="openInTab('http://www.google.com');">Click me</button>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function openInTab(source){
                var newTab=safari.self.browserWindow.openTab();
                newTab.url=source;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body style="color:#C02020;background:#C0C0C0;">
        <a href="javascript:openInTab('http://www.google.com');"> Google </a>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use `target_blank`?

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp

Comment: I have tried with both _blank and target_blank but neither seems to work. My bar.html is always the page being opened instead of 'google.com', and in the same tab, not a new one.